# UI Stopped working

Tags: android, user-interface

I have developed an android app using android studio and it was running well until I made several layout changes. When I download my app on any android phone, it causes the phone's UI to stop working. If my app is not installed, the phone works perfectly fine.I checked the log and there seemed to be no error. Are there any reasons as to why an app may cause such a crash? 
Also, the app displays this message when the Overview softkey is pressed

Thanks in advance:)

Log

```
     [ 04-25 10:18:47.942  1621: 1867 W/         ]
                                                     Unrecognized GLES 
max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 
ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
04-25 10:18:48.013 2897-2918/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:18:48.017 2897-2918/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Scheduling upload with JobScheduler
04-25 10:18:48.018 2897-2918/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Scheduling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:18:48.039 2897-2918/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Background event processing time, ms: 151
04-25 10:18:48.388 2897-2897/com.securitytechno2018 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
04-25 10:18:48.389 2897-2897/com.securitytechno2018 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
04-25 10:18:52.913 2897-2918/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
04-25 10:18:52.915 2897-2897/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: onUnbind called for intent. action: com.google.android.gms.measurement.START
04-25 10:18:52.916 2897-2897/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is shutting down
04-25 10:19:23.118 2897-2970/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Using local app measurement service
04-25 10:19:23.129 2897-2970/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 529158
04-25 10:19:23.371 2897-2897/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is starting up
04-25 10:19:23.532 2897-2897/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Bound to IMeasurementService interface
04-25 10:19:23.532 2897-2970/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Connected to service
04-25 10:19:23.534 2897-2970/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
04-25 10:19:28.535 2897-2970/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
04-25 10:19:28.536 2897-2897/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: onUnbind called for intent. action: com.google.android.gms.measurement.START
04-25 10:19:28.536 2897-2897/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is shutting down
04-25 10:19:32.882 2897-2897/com.securitytechno2018 W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
04-25 10:19:46.346 2972-2989/com.securitytechno2018 E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.
04-25 10:19:46.403 2972-2972/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:19:46.408 2972-2972/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
04-25 10:19:46.435 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Collection enabled
04-25 10:19:46.435 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: App package, google app id: com.securitytechno2018, 1:702727695830:android:1ac1b0e480da2fe9
04-25 10:19:46.439 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11910
04-25 10:19:46.439 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
04-25 10:19:46.440 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                            adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.securitytechno2018
04-25 10:19:46.440 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
04-25 10:19:46.463 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Checking service availability
04-25 10:19:46.466 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 W/FA: Service invalid
04-25 10:19:46.468 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Using local app measurement service
04-25 10:19:46.477 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
04-25 10:19:46.477 2972-2972/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: onActivityCreated
04-25 10:19:47.220 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
04-25 10:19:47.222 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 553266
04-25 10:19:47.231 2972-2972/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is starting up
04-25 10:19:47.246 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashScreen, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3593885112120958867}]
04-25 10:19:47.263 2972-2972/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Bound to IMeasurementService interface
04-25 10:19:47.280 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
04-25 10:19:47.281 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Connected to service
04-25 10:19:47.281 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
04-25 10:19:47.285 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 I/FA: This instance being marked as an uploader
04-25 10:19:47.327 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3163502

                                                          [ 04-25 10:19:47.329  2972: 2972 D/         ]
                                                          HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa4bf5fc0, tid 2972
04-25 10:19:47.332 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:19:47.333 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Scheduling upload with JobScheduler
04-25 10:19:47.333 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Scheduling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:19:47.342 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Parsed config. version, gmp_app_id: 1520959753892242, 1:702727695830:android:1ac1b0e480da2fe9
04-25 10:19:47.345 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 D/FA: Unable to get advertising id: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzchx.zzjm(Unknown Source)
04-25 10:19:47.365 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 W/FA: Callable skipped the worker queue.
04-25 10:19:47.375 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashScreen, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3593885112120958867}]
04-25 10:19:47.389 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Saving event, name, data size: screen_view(_vs), 57
04-25 10:19:47.390 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.securitytechno2018', name='screen_view(_vs)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashScreen, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3593885112120958867}]}
04-25 10:19:47.394 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3163435
04-25 10:19:47.397 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:19:47.398 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Scheduling upload with JobScheduler
04-25 10:19:47.399 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Scheduling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:19:47.400 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Background event processing time, ms: 25

                                                          [ 04-25 10:19:47.408  2972: 2972 W/         ]
                                                          Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
04-25 10:19:48.251 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1019
04-25 10:19:48.256 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Activity paused, time: 554281
04-25 10:19:48.256 2972-2972/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: onActivityCreated
04-25 10:19:48.262 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1019, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashScreen, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3593885112120958867}]
04-25 10:19:48.361 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Logging event: origin=auto,name=user_engagement(_e),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1019, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashScreen, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3593885112120958867}]
04-25 10:19:48.480 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Saving event, name, data size: user_engagement(_e), 67
04-25 10:19:48.481 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.securitytechno2018', name='user_engagement(_e)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=1019, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SplashScreen, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3593885112120958867}]}
04-25 10:19:48.495 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3162334
04-25 10:19:48.511 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:19:48.514 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Scheduling upload with JobScheduler
04-25 10:19:48.514 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Scheduling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:19:48.521 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Background event processing time, ms: 160
04-25 10:19:48.831 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 554878
04-25 10:19:48.833 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SplashScreen, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=3593885112120958867, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=RegisterActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3593885112120958868}]
04-25 10:19:48.852 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SplashScreen, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=3593885112120958867, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=RegisterActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3593885112120958868}]
04-25 10:19:48.864 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Saving event, name, data size: screen_view(_vs), 99
04-25 10:19:48.865 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.securitytechno2018', name='screen_view(_vs)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=SplashScreen, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=3593885112120958867, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=RegisterActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3593885112120958868}]}
04-25 10:19:48.867 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3161962
04-25 10:19:48.870 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:19:48.871 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Scheduling upload with JobScheduler
04-25 10:19:48.872 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Scheduling job. JobID: 2074818501
04-25 10:19:48.875 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Background event processing time, ms: 23
04-25 10:19:53.853 2972-2993/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
04-25 10:19:53.855 2972-2972/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: onUnbind called for intent. action: com.google.android.gms.measurement.START
04-25 10:19:53.855 2972-2972/com.securitytechno2018 V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is shutting down
```

Comment: Please read this first [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: try to add some code and logcat in question

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to new changes you have applied to your application is not compatible with your current API level... try updating all the library and API-level of your application ... and check which library is causing an issue ...